# Do we have any trick for doing $\int_0^L \left( \int_0^x f(s) \ ds \right)\left(\int_0^x g(t) \ dt\right) dx$?

Tags: integration

sir.

As mentioned in the tile, what I want to do is doing this calculation.

$$
\int_0^L \left( \int_0^x f(s) \ ds \right)\left(\int_0^x g(t) \ dt\right) dx
$$

Here, $f$ and $g$ can not be explicitly integrated.

I want to eliminate a double integral.

Do we have any tricks for avoiding a double integral?

Answer (score 0):

You can always do

$$
\int_0^L \left( \int_0^x f(s) \ ds \right)\left(\int_0^x g(t) \ dt\right) dx
$$

$$
=\int_0^L  \int_0^x \int_0^x g(t) f(s) \ ds   \ dt \ dx
$$
The order of this integral can then be switched around to
$$
=\int_0^L  \int_0^t \int_0^s g(t) f(s) \ dx  \ ds \ dt
$$
which might be integrable in this order.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. In your answer, we have a triple integral rather than a double integral. Actually, I want to avoid double or triple or any other higher order integral. I'd like to express my formula with a combination of single integral by using a technique like integral by parts or anything like that. Could you please help me one more time?

Comment: Since you said that $f$ and $g$ cannot be explicitly integrated, I took this approach.  I don't think there's any other way to do it if they can't be explicitly integrated.